# what's a "sign-off process"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I am translating a text which says that during the probation period, the direct report monitors the new employee's performance through a sign-off process.

what does sign-off mean in this context? Or is "sign-off process" some kind term?

Comment: In this context it's a reference to the fact that some relevant representative from management has to *sign* a document confirming that the employee's probationary period has been successfully completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also heard this referred to as a "passport" process, where the individual under review will go through a series of events or stages.

In order to advance, he or she must successfully complete the stages, and a reviewer "signs off", indicating successful completion.

Answer (score -2):

Think about reporters, when they say, "This is [REPORTER NAME] signing off." To sign off means to leave. I'm not sure where this sentence is going though with the term "sign off," especially since it is hyphenated rather than separated.

Comment: This is an entirely different meaning of _sign off_. THEAO's answer is correct. (and it wasn't me that downvoted).